# execute immediate oracle string concatenate issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, concatenation, execute, utl-mail

I am having issues concatenating a string to be called be execute immediate. Anybody have any idea what is wrong with the following statement below.

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''||SMTPServer||''';

```
select smtpserver into SMTPServer from mytable;

if(SMTPServer is not null)
then
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''||SMTPServer||''';
  --*****above does not work, below does work****
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''10.1.1.1''';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the standpoint of building the string you want, you're missing a couple of single quotes.  You'd need 3 single quotes before and four single quotes after the `SMTPServer` local variable

```
'ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ''' || smtpServer || ''''
```

Personally, I'd find it easier to do something like this where you declare a template (using the q quoting syntax since it has embedded single quotes), call `replace` to replace the templated values, and then call `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  It's a bit more code but it generally makes life easier.

```
l_sql_stmt := q'{ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = '##server##'}';
l_sql_stmt := replace( l_sql_stmt, '##server##', smtpServer );
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
```

Are you sure that the second statement really works, though?  `smtp_out_server` isn't supposed to be [modifiable without a database restart](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams230.htm#REFRN10241).  I've seen folks say that they've been able to modify it successfully with an `ALTER SYSTEM` at runtime but haven't seen anyone try to do it with an `ALTER SESSION`.  I'd hesitate to build code that depends on behavior that goes against the documentation.  If you need to control the SMTP server you're using at runtime, I'd strongly suggest using the `utl_smtp` package rather than `utl_mail`.

Comment: thank you very much, that worked. I will also look into your other suggestions, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really good providing the statement for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE replacing the parameters, since for the optmizer it's a completely different statement every single time so it prepares another execution plan for each.
You should use binding in your EXECUTE IMMEDIATE clause.

Example:

```
DECLARE
  SMTPServer mytable.smtpserver%type;

  l_set_smtpserver_stmt VARCHAR2(600) := q'#ALTER SESSION SET smtp_out_server = ':p_smtp_server'#'

BEGIN
  SELECT smtpserver INTO SMTPServer FROM mytable;

  IF SMTPServer IS NOT NULL THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_set_smtpserver_stmt USING SMTPServer;
  END IF;


  EXCEPTION
    -- handle no_data_found exception since you're using select .. into statement
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        -- handle exception
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- handle exception
END;
/
```